# Attach jQuery keypress event to get keyCode

Tags: javascript

I want to add a keypress event to all `input[type=text]` so that when you type in the input it will alert each keyCode.

I'm getting stuck on the logic of the `event` part and whether this can be handled this way?

```js
$("#my-form input[type=text]").keypress(function(event) {
  alert(event.keyCode);
}
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="my-form">
<input type="text" id="my-id-1">
<input type="text" id="my-id-2">
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: If you type something in either one of the fields, the keyCode is alerted as 0.

Comment: Not so for me, worked entirely as intended. Have you tried running the snippet from your post directly?

Comment: I run the snippet directly from your post and see nothing's wrong.

Comment: Hrmm, seems to only be Firefox that's returning 0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `event.key` (for Firefox) should be what you're looking for. Here's the 
code with it.

```js
$("#my-form input[type=text]").keypress(function(event) {
  alert(event.key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="my-form">
<input type="text" id="my-id-1">
<input type="text" id="my-id-2">
</form>
```

Keep in mind though, the `keypress` event may have differing behavior [across browsers](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/), which is why you're seeing "0" on Firefox, and for others the behavior is normal.

Comment: keyCode is listed as deprecated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress), which is why you should instead use the `key` property.

Comment: @obermillerk yup, forgot to add that. Thanks.